# Prove that if $x\leq y$ then $x+z\leq y+z$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

Does the below proof looks correct for the above question?

$$\text{Either x = y or (y - x) $\in $ }\mathbb{R}^+$$
$$\text{Case 1: x=y $\forall $z$\in $}\mathbb{R}^+$$
$$\text{x+z=y+z}$$ 
$$\text{Case 2: x $<$ y $\forall $z$\in $}\mathbb{R}^+$$
$$\text{(y + z) - (x + z) = y + z - x - z = (y - x)$\in $}\mathbb{R}^+$$
And so $(y-x)$ is a positive number implies y >0

In particular we have $$x\leq y $$

Could someone verify?

Comment: I posted an answer, but the end of your proof actually has me a little confused.  You are supposed to assume $x \leq y$ (which you did) and prove $x + z \leq y + z$.  So your proof should end with what you wanted to show, which is $x + z \leq y + z$.  You ended with $x \leq y$, but that was what we started out assuming in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand and agree with every step of your proof.  But I think the way you presented your proof as a list of steps with few words makes it difficult to read.  I think you should write out your proof like a story.  It's easier to follow than having step after step in a list.

Here's how I would have written the proof using the same steps as you, but presented in a more readable way:

> **Problem:** Let $x, y, z \in \Bbb R$ and suppose $x \leq y$.  Prove $x + z \leq y + z$.
>
> **Proof:** Since $x \leq y$, then either $x = y$, or $x < y$.
>
> If $x = y$, then for any $z$, $x + z = y + z$, so it follows that $x + z \leq y + z$.
>
> Now, if $x < y$, then $y - x > 0$.  This implies $y + 0 - x > 0$ which implies $y + (z - z) - x > 0$, and this implies $(y + z) - (x + z) > 0$.  Finally, this implies $y + z > x + z$, so we get that $y + z \geq x + z$.
>
> Thus, we have shown in every case that $x + z \leq y + z$, as desired.

Comment: Questions like these annoy me so much--it's very important to state what you are allowed to assume and that is almost never done by OP for some reason. Kudos for answering though.

Comment: @crash But isn't it in the title?

Comment: I meant in terms of axioms.

Comment: @crash Yeah, I guess you're right.  Proofs can look completely different depending on what you are allowed to use.

Answer (score -1):

I was not sure how to give a definite answer to this so I decided to show a proof that I know works. Let us say that y-x=a, (x+z)-(y+z)=b, and a is greater than or equal to 0. This means that if our proof is correct, b will be greater than or equal to 0. So, what happens with (x+z)-(y+z)? Well, it also equals a because that anything minus itself equals 0, and anything plus 0 equals itself. So, not only is b greater than or equal to 0, but also a=b! Sorry this dose not answer your question, but I hope it is useful anyway!