# Doesn’t this proof of $x < y \implies x + z < y + z$ use its own result in it?

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

> **Problem:** Let $x, y, z \in \Bbb R$ and suppose $x \leq y$.  Prove $x + z \leq y + z$.
>
> **Proof:** Since $x \leq y$, then either $x = y$, or $x < y$.
>
> If $x = y$, then for any $z$, $x + z = y + z$, so it follows that $x + z \leq y + z$.
>
> Now, if $x < y$, then $y - x > 0$.  This implies $y + 0 - x > 0$ which implies $y + (z - z) - x > 0$, and this implies $(y + z) - (x + z) > 0$.  Finally, this implies $y + z > x + z$, so we get that $y + z \geq x + z$.
>
> Thus, we have shown in every case that $x + z \leq y + z$, as desired.

Here is the proof from layman in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1219350/. This is the proof I have been taught in school as well.

However something bugs me in this part:

> this implies $(y + z) - (x + z) > 0$. Finally, this implies $y + z > x + z$

Here, we “move” $(x + z)$, so to speak, to the right side. But doesn’t it mean adding $(x + z)$ to both sides and assuming the inequality still stands? Isn’t it precisely what is being proven?

Comment: The confusing part here is that you're trying to prove a new result by relying only on previous results, and it's hard to tell what results are part of these "previous results" and which are not, given that every result is kind of trivial. Presumably the previous results include hypotheses such as $z \geq 0$, so what the proof is doing is trying to extend this previous result to the general case.

Comment: You need to go down to the definition of $>$. There are several ways to do so. One is first defining the meaning of $x>0$ and then defining $x>y$ as equivalent to $x-y>0$ (which is already defined). If that was the path followed here then going from $(y+z)-(x+z)>0$ to $y+z > x+z$ is just by definition.

Comment: In an ordered field $x > y \implies x+ z > y +z$ is an axiom. Since you're proving this for $\geq$ you simply need to solve the equality case and use this for the inequality case. You may be using that $x > y$ if $ x-y > 0$ in which case the $x+z$ term can be moved directly as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a proof like this, here's one very important thing: you must spell out (at least in your own mind) precisely which theorems/axioms/definitions are already *known*, in order that you know what you can apply for purposes of proving a new theorem.

Also, you should write your proof by *applying* a known theorem/axiom/definition at every step.

Your proof is all a mush, I cannot tell at all what is already known, although in some cases it seems implicit and so I can guess what is probably already known.

Let me start with your first sentence:

> Since $x \le y$, then either $x=y$ or $x<y$.

Okay, implicit there is that the statement "$x \le y$ implies $x=y$ or $x<y$" is already known. In fact, I would guess that the stronger statement "$x \le y$ if and only if ($x=y$ or $x<y$)" is already known. But even here, there is room for more clarity: I am unsure whether this is a previously proved *theorem*, or perhaps a *definition*, or even an *axiom*. What I would really guess is that it is a definition: "$x \le y$" is **defined** to mean "$x=y$ or $x<y$".

Moving on,

> If $x=y$, then for any $z$, $x+z=y+z$, so it follows that $x+z \le y+z$.

My guess is that what is implicit here is the fact that addition is a well-defined binary operation. Furthermore, my guess is that this is an **axiom**.

Next,

> Now, if $x<y$ then $y-x>0$.

Now, things are getting tricky. How do you know this? My best guess is that there is a known statement of the form

> (*) $a<b$ if and only if $b-a>0$.

and so what you are applying is the "only if" direction of $(*)$. (What might be better is that "$b>a$ if and only if $b-a>0$" is a known statement, coupled with a definition that says "$c<d$ is defined to mean $d>c$").

What I *cannot* guess is the nature of statement $(*)$, namely theorem, or definition, or axiom. Well, I'm sure it is not a definition of strict inequality because that would be circular. Perhaps it is either a theorem or an axiom, but I am unsure. In some treatments, the concept of "positive numbers" and its properties are part of the axioms, and the statement "$b>a$" is defined to mean "$b-a$ is positive". If that's the case, you might have already proved an earlier theorem of the form "$b>a$ if and only if $b-a>0$".

Anyway, I think I've made my point without trying to make further guesses. It is the responsibility of *you* to know what is known and can be applied in your present proof.

Finally, you ask about the step

> this implies $(y+z)-(x+z)>0$. Finally, this implies $y+z>x+z$.

Well, if you do indeed already know that the if-and-only-if statement $(*)$ is true, then you can apply the "if" direction of that statement using $b=y+z$ and $a=x+z$.